# Price toggle with upsell remover/adder

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a working price toggler, that also has an upsell remover/adder. While it works well, I'd like to understand how I could do it better, because I'm having to essentially run two compound if/else statements to account for the duration toggle and the upsell toggle.

```js
const pricing = document.querySelector('#toggle');

var single = pricing.dataset.scMonthly;
var both = pricing.dataset.bothMonthly;
var bc = pricing.dataset.bcMonthly;
var price = both;

function setPackage(){
    if (document.getElementById("package").checked == true) {
        if (document.getElementById("toggle").checked == true) {
            var price = both;
            document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
        } else {
            var price = both * 10;
            document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
        }
    } else {
        if (document.getElementById("toggle").checked == true) {
            var price = single;
            document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
        } else {
            var price = single * 10;
            document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
        }
    }
}

function setPrice() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll('.annual');
    var y = document.querySelectorAll('.month');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById("toggle").checked == true) {
            x[i].classList.add('hidden');
            y[i].classList.remove('hidden');
            if (document.getElementById("package").checked == true) {
                document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = both;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = single;
            }
            document.getElementById("bcValue").innerHTML = bc;
        } else {
            x[i].classList.remove('hidden');
            y[i].classList.add('hidden');

            if (document.getElementById("package").checked == true) {
                document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = both * 10;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = single * 10;
            }
            document.getElementById("bcValue").innerHTML = bc * 10;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Annually</p>

    <!-- Toggle Button -->
    <label for="toggle">
        <!-- toggle -->
        <div class="relative">
            <!-- hidden input -->
            <input
                id="toggle"
                type="checkbox"
                class="hidden"
                onclick="setPrice()"
                data-sc-monthly="59"
                data-both-monthly="79"
                data-bc-monthly="20"
             />
            <!-- line -->
            <div></div>
            <!-- dot -->
            <div class="toggle_dot"></div>
        </div>
    </label>

    <p>Monthly</p>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <h3>Main Report</h3>
        <h4>$<span id="price">790</span></h4>
        <p><span class="annual">ANNUALLY</span><span class="month hidden">MONTHLY</span></p>
        <div>
            <input
            id="package"
            type="checkbox"
            onclick="setPackage()"
            checked
            />
            <h5>Include our special secondary coverage for just $<span id="bcValue">200</span></h5>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-success">
            JOIN NOW
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, each function has to check if the parameters controlled by the other function are set or not, and make adjustments accordingly.

My JS-fu is not strong enough yet to figure out how to improve this code overall.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would also consider using radio buttons instead of a checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your `for` loop in `setPrice` has a lot of code that does not vary between iterations of the loop. The loop only needs to add or remove the relevant class property, and the other code should be outside the loop. A couple of helper functions may be useful to take care of this.

```
function hideAll(query) {
    for (const element of document.querySelectorAll(query)) {
        element.classList.add("hidden");
    }
}
function showAll(query) {
    for (const element of document.querySelectorAll(query)) {
        element.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
}
```

2. For the rest of the code, write a single function that updates values taking into account the status of all checkboxes. This will be triggered whenever anything changes in the form. This may mean some very minor inefficiencies (updating the `innerHTML` of `bcValue` when it hasn't actually changed) but will dramatically simplify the code. (If your page does eventually become much more complicated, you could write some extra code to check whether relevant values have changed before updating them on the page. It will still be simpler and easier to maintain than having every tick-box trigger a different function which independently updates the same set of values.)

```
function update() {
    const package = document.getElementById("package").checked ? both : single;
    let factor;
    if (document.getElementById("toggle").checked) {
        factor = 1;
        hideAll(".annual");
        showAll(".month");
    } else {
        factor = 10;
        showAll(".annual");
        hideAll(".month");
    }
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = package * factor;
    document.getElementById("bcValue").innerHTML = bc * factor;
}
```

3. It's usually better to set event listeners within javascript instead of in the HTML, making it easier to change, add more complicated behaviors, and having all of the logic in one place.

```
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", update);
document.getElementById("package").addEventListener("click", update);
```

```
for (const id of ["toggle", "package"]) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("click", update);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I put your code in a JSBin to test it out, but I'm not seeing anything happen in `setPrice()`, so I looked at `setPackage()`.

The first thing you can do in `setPackage` is take out the four lines where you set the `innerHTML` and put one copy of that line *after* the if/then/else that sets the price.

I also think that you wrote `**var** price = <some value>` several times, but meant to write just `price = <some value>` as price is declared earlier.

Finally, do you know about the ternary operator (?:) in JavaScript? It's very useful for if/then/else constructions.

With these three suggestions, your `function setPackage()` could look like this:

```
function setPackage(){
  var cond1 = document.getElementById("package").checked === true
  var cond2 = document.getElementById("toggle").checked === true

  price = cond1 
      ? (cond2 ? both : both * 10) 
      : (cond2 ? single : single * 10)

  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
}
```

Comment: No need to nest the ternaries here - the OP's code actually does `price = (cond1 ? both : single) * (cond2 ? 1 : 10);`

Comment: And drop the `=== true`.

Comment: Thanks for both your comments. Much cleaner.